# Concept of laravel first() method

Tags: laravel, eloquent

The laravel `first()` method is pretty straight forward and that's why this question might be silly, but I am not understanding the use of `first()` method.

Actually, I'm following a youtube tutorial where I am authenticating a user if he has the role of `admin` then only he will get the access of `route` otherwise will be redirected to `home`.

There is no error or issue with code but my understanding.

I am returning the user in `User` model class function if the user has the role passed by the middleware

Route

```php
Route::get('admin', function (){
     return 'This is Admin page';
})->middleware(['auth', 'auth.admin']);
```

Middleware

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth::user()->hasAnyRole('admin'))
    {
        return $next($request);
    }
    return redirect('home');
}
```

User Modal

```php
public function hasAnyRole($role)
{
    return null !== $this->roles()->where('name', $role)->first();
}
```

If I use `first()` method in `hasAnyRole` function then only `route` is protected by other users and only `admin` get access to the route,
If I remove the `first()` method then all the users get access to `route` which I don't understand why?

Comment: You have to send that SQL. Using `get()` or `first()`. If you don't use these methods, then your eloquent object is never `null`. Meaning, you never get the results.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to the docs:

> The first method returns the first element in the collection that passes a given truth test:

```php
collect([1, 2, 3, 4])->first(function ($value, $key) {
    return $value > 2;
});
// 3
```

> You may also call the first method with no arguments to get the first element in the collection. If the collection is empty, null is returned:

```php
collect([1, 2, 3, 4])->first();
// 1
```

In your question, if you don't use the `first()` method, it will return a collection with no data, like:

```php
Roles {#1
    []
}
```

This empty collection is not equals to `null`.

**About the `!==` operator**

```php
$x !== $y
```

It the previous snippet, it returns true if $x is not equal to $y, or they are not of the same type.

So, in your code:

```php
return null !== $this->roles()->where('name', $role)->first();
```

it will return `true` if (and only if) the user doesn't have the required role, what you get done by the `first()` method:

```php
$this->roles()->where('name', 'admin')->first();
```

If the user doesn't have the `admin` role, then it returns `null`, what is identical and  same type of `null` (in your comparison). So it returns `false`, cause `null !== null` returns false, and the access is not granted.

If you use something like

```php
$this->roles()->where('name', 'admin');
```

and the user does not have the `admin` role, it return something like this:

```php
Roles {#1
    []
}
```

Now your `hasAnyRole` function returns `true` and the access is granted to the user, since the empty collection is not of the same type and also not equals to `null`;

Docs about the [`first`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-first) method.