# GetKey method returns null in dataSnapshot

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm a beginner struggling to grasp Android Studio and I'm currently stuck on a problem. I'm trying to pull a read data from my Database in text view. When I use getKey method, it returns null even though there are values in the DB. Note I am trying to display "name" (222) in a text view box.
Here is my code

Comment: what this `dataSnapshot.getKey()` provide to you log that key. I think it provides you current user id which you passing in query

Comment: Yeah it is providing me with user ID, why is that?

Comment: Because your trying to retrive the get the parent key by using that method. For your information i suggest to go something like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to retrieve the `name`, then try the following:

```
        ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(currentuser).child("Teams");
        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

               for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                a = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.test1);
                a.setText(name);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
              throw databaseError.toException();
            }


        });
```

First add a reference to node `Teams` then iterate and retrieve the value of `name`

Comment: i think it's bad way to do something like this. As he didn't tell us proper number of childrens available in Teams. So i suggest something like [first()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56516181/concept-of-laravel-first-method). Might be useful

Comment: check the image again under teams there is an id and under that there is 3 attributes. Then under these 3 attributes another parent node is created not related to Teams

Comment: Great thank you very much. This worked the charm! :)

Comment: I am just suggesting something like first() which will return the first child from other.

Comment: WHat exactly is the for loop doing?

Comment: @hanzn98 the loop iterate inside your random id to be able to access `name`,`age` and `coach`